# Enable Magento Varien_Profiler in frontend area

Tags: magento, frontend, profiler

How do I enable Magento Profiler in the frontend area?

I've set the admin option, uncommented `Varien_Profiler::enable();` in my index.php and cleared cache, and verified that but the profiler results only show in admin?

The Profiler is enabled in the default configuration scope in **System > Configuration > Developer** and that Developer IP Restrictions are empty.

Am I missing something else?

Comment: Running into same issue. Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: I ended up just doing fresh install. The problem didn't reappear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup not only the Profiler but the configuration scope. Every scope has a profiler setting. See the top left corner select box (current configuration scope) in the admin.